# How do I check if column was removed?

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable with a lot of redundant columns. The user has options to customize the table which removes the columns by calling:

```
Table.removeColumn(Table.getColumnModel().getColumn(11));
```

When I close the program , settings are saved. But I cannot find a way to check if columns are  visible or not (removed using that command) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could save which columns are visible based on the column name using the `getColumnCount()` and `getColumnName(int column)` methods.

```
int numColumns = jTable.getColumnCount()
for(int index = 0; index < numColumns; index++)
{
   String name = jTable.getColumnName(index);
   // add name to list and save after iteration
}
```